# Does sudden cooling of SSD affects it?

Tags: ssd

I've got computer without chassis that lies simply in motherboard-box-package.
I ventilated my apartment (opened windows at both ends), it's -10C(14F) outside and strong wind and pc not far from window, in 10min I was thrown out of X and pc froze. After reboot I found out that BIOS does not see SSD(Kingstone), on touch ssd was pretty cold. I warmed it in my hands for couple minutes and it worked again.

Do I need to prevent ssd from cooling hereafter, or just extreme cooling? Maybe there is something bad with this particular ssd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify which Kingston SSD you were using, so I'm assuming it's the SSDNow V100. I suspect others are similar.

According to [this page](http://www.thessdreview.com/our-reviews/kingston-ssdnow-v100-128b-ssd-review/), the Kingston SSDNow V100 is specced to operate at temperatures from 0°C to 70°C and may be stored at temperatures from -40°C to 85°C. While -10°C is not that cold, it is outside the specifications of the drive. In general, I wouldn't advise operating a computer below about +10°C.

Comment: I really didn't think that such non-mechanical device will malfunction at that kind of temperatures. -10°C it's outdoors and pc few meters from window, I don't think ssd went much lower than 0°C. Anyway, will assume that that was just out of operate temperatures.

Comment: @user2777737 the issue is condensation. Below 0C you may get ice forming, when it gets warm it will turn to water, and water on your circuitry is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Kingston specifies an operating temperature range of 0 to 70 degrees Celsius for their SSDs (at least the ones I could find on [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA0AJ15M1062)). You can store them at a wider range of temperatures (-40C to 85C), but they are not guaranteed to operate at below-freezing temperatures.