# What, if anything, should I do about an SSD reporting low temperatures?

Tags: ssd, cooling, temperature, smart, m.2

Kubuntu's disk monitoring feature has recently (last few weeks) started giving me alerts about an imminent disk failure on my NVMe M.2 SSD (a Crucial P2) at boot. I have been running  `sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme` and get output such as this:

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        3 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          5%
Percentage Used:                    1%
Data Units Read:                    15,515,158 [7.94 TB]
Data Units Written:                 16,500,632 [8.44 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 193,875,355
Host Write Commands:                227,509,455
Controller Busy Time:               13,258
Power Cycles:                       1,402
Power On Hours:                     4,282
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   164
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      2,609
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 16 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0       2609     0  0x1000  0x4005  0x028            0     0     -
```

Running [HDSentinel](https://www.hdsentinel.com/hard_disk_sentinel_linux.php) provided independent confirmation of the results, for example:

```
Temperature  : -3 °C
Highest Temp.: -3 °C
Health       : 50 %
Performance  : 100 %
  The following error(s) detected:
  Temperature is above the over-temperature threshold / below the under-temperature threshold.
  The health is determined by SSD specific S.M.A.R.T. attribute(s):  Available Spare (Percent), Percentage Used
    It is recommended to continuously monitor the hard disk status.
```

So the problem appears to be low temperature and I am mostly seeing values between -3 and 3°C even after the system has been running for some time. Occasionally it gets to a saner level like 27°C. When it's 0°C or below then it shows a critical warning code. Both the SSD datasheet and the consensus from [the closest question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/709819/does-sudden-cooling-of-ssd-affects-it) say that 0°C is indeed the lowest intended operating temp. Anecdotal evidence from [another question about an SSD not booting](https://superuser.com/questions/735535/why-wont-my-ssd-boot-when-its-cold) suggest that cold temps can be a consequence rather than a cause of disk failure, but my SSD has never failed so far.

The reported temperatures are lower than the outside air temps, never mind the temp is in the room, which gets chilly at night, but not *that* cold! And I have a bog-standard cooling setup: the fan built into the case and the AMD Wraith Spire cooler that came with the APU. Is it really possible that the airflow could lower the SSD temp by 10-20°?!

What, if anything, should I do about this?:

- Yes, all important data is already backed up frequently and in multiple locations (thank you, [Duplicati](https://www.duplicati.com/)!).
- Could this be a failure of the temperature sensor? Is there any way to check this or get more detailed info from the SMART data?
- I could try to return the SSD (it's still in warranty) but I'd have to buy another one anyway if I RMAd it plus the faff of reinstalling everything.
- Searching online for "SSD heating" or "SSD insulation" just gets me cooling solutions. Is there something I could safely buy or make to warm up the SSD?
- Any other thoughts?

Comment: Can you find another utility to read the temperature? Maybe smartctl and your SSD are not (yet) compatible.

Comment: The only reasonnable and logical conclusion is that the reported temperature is **wrong**, for some reason. No component can be colder than the ambient temperature (unless there's a heat pump in the PC (joke))

Comment: After the machine has been running for 30 minutes, shut it down, ground yourself and gently touch the surface of the SSD. I much doubt it will be 0 degrees C.  I have an InfraRed thermometer that is great for this if you have access to one.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for this suggestion. I have done some searching and it seems that most other utilities just wrappers for smartctl. I did discover though that (a) smartctl should support nvme self-tests from its next release (see https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/894) and (b) something called nvme-cli which may support self-tests.

Comment: @Matthew, FWIW HD Sentinel is not a wrapper around smartctl.

Comment: Do you experience any issues with that drive? If no: [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Note that Temp is not a collected stat, but the immediate output of a sensors. software often has trouble reading all the different sensors that manufacturers implement.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Thank you for the helpful tip! I tested with HDSentinel and got the same results, which I have added to the question.

Comment: @mashuptwice KDE is warning that my hard drive is about to fail. That is obviously an actual problem; it would be absurd to wait for my disk to fail (making my PC unusable) before I could ask for help.

Comment: While you're there, please post the full SMART report, to see why a poor health is reported. If it's just because of the temperature then you can safely ignore that: once again the only explanation is a wrong reported temperature for some reason (the sensor has failed or whatever).

Comment: This *is* the full SMART health data. NVMe SMART is very different from SATA SMART.

Comment: Is this a "cheap" SSD?  IE, not name brand?  I do see on occasion these off brand manufacturers use faulty thermal sensors.  I have a cheap ADATA drive that always reports the temperarature as 100C, yet in reality it isnt.

Comment: @Keltari No, it's Crucial, which is the main brand of Micron, one of the big 3 memory manufacturers, with a 3-year warranty. It was the cheapest product in their line though!

Answer (score 0):

> What, if anything, should I do about this?

- Between -3 and 3°C is blatantly wrong.
- Use common sense: the value reported by the software is wrong.

So, your immediate actions should be:

- do nothing until you are not under stress for this item
- find software which reports accurate values (possibly [Storage Executive Software](https://www.micron.com/products/ssd/storage-executive-software) from Micron)
- find out if any temperatures reported are of any concern in reality
- find cooling/heating systems which ensure reliable data storage/retrieval on the storage device

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated the answer to show that two independent software suites are giving identical answers. So the problem must be in hardware/firmware, not software. I am leaning towards a failed thermal sensor but want to try an external thermometer to be sure.

Comment: @Matthew There's no need to buy a thermometer to check if something is that cold: it will have ice or condensation on it and it will definitely feel cold to the touch.

Comment: @Matthew I added a link to Micron's own SSD Linux utility, but I don't have the appropriate hardware to try it for myself.